# Packer Digital Ocean FIPS Mode cannot ssh

Tags: linux, openssh, centos-8

I'm using Packer to build a Centos 8 box on Digital Ocean with FIPS mode enabled.

```
# setup.sh script
fips-mode-setup --enabled
```

Then I use Terraform to provision an Droplet with that new image, and copy over my SSH key to the new droplet. I generate my SSH key like so:

```
ssh-keygen -o -a 100 -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

When the Droplet is provisioned, I can no longer SSH in (when FIPS mode is disabled, I am able to SSH in with the same SSH key).

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why _are_ you using FIPS mode? This is kind of literally what FIPS mode does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIPS mode for a cryptographic module requires that cryptographic software use only approved cryptographic algorithms, among other requirements.  Ed25519 is not considered one of these algorithms, so SSH is told to intentionally disable support for that when in FIPS mode.

In general, Ed25519 is a good choice and is widely recommended by cryptographers and security experts, and should be your preferred choice if it's possible.  Unless you are certain you need to comply with FIPS 140-2, you should definitely disable FIPS mode because it disables useful, fast, and secure algorithms like Ed25519, ChaCha, and BLAKE2.  You're better off following the advice of trusted organizations like Mozilla when configuring SSH and TLS.

If, however, you need to enable FIPS mode for compliance reasons, you cannot use an Ed25519 key.  Your backup should be a 256-bit ECDSA key, which is the most likely to be implemented in a constant-time (and therefore secure) way.